# Clarification on Dummy Variables

Tags: ordinal-data, categorical-encoding

When it comes to categorical variables, they should only be converted to dummy variables if the nature of the categorical variable doesn't have any sense of structure (such as: high, medium, low).

Meaning that a categorical variable that includes: Tea, Soda, Coffee, Water is a good example of a categorical variable that could be converted into dummy features.
Is this correct?

If so, what about a variable such as Region: Northeast, Northwest, Southeast, or Southwest?
Is this one simply not converted into dummy data because they all relate to each other in some form?

My question is: **When and why are categorical variables converted into dummy variables?**

Quick Note: I read something briefly that it has to do with categorical data being converted into numerical data either way so using dummy data prevents any unwanted influence from being introduced.

Answer (score 0):

When and where are dummy $(0,1)$ variables used?

Below are the situations where the possible problems can be averted resorting to dummy $(0,1)$ variables:

$\bullet$ When you want to allocate codes to non-quantitative variables but they are arbitrary. Take, for example, you have four occupations: two of those being self-employed and artisan. If you assign $4$ to the former and $2$ to the latter, the codes *measuring* the occupational status, what does that even mean? Does the self-employed have $2$ times more occupational status than the artisan? When there is arbitrariness in the allocation of codes, the consequence is that inherently you are imposing value difference on the categories of the variables.

Examples being soil type; religion; geographical regions etc.

$\bullet$ Even if when the variables are more measurable than *occupation* like education where the variables are grouped into categories defined as high school graduate, college graduate, foreign education, one may encounter problem in classifying someone with a foreign education but with this country's doctorate.

Relevant examples of situations like this can be found in income; city size, etc. It's just not practical and rational enough to allocate codes on grouped variables like these.

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ Linear Models, *S. R. Searle,* John Wiley & Sons., $1971,$ sec. $4.1,$ pp. $136-137.$